# Scrolled to the bottom when ads (admob) loaded in recyclerview in android

Tags: android-recyclerview, admob

I have a `recyclerview` with 7 items in it. In the bottom of the list, I insert a banner of `admob`. I have inserted successfully.However, when the ads (in the bottom of the list) loaded, it automatically scrolled my view to the bottom.

I have used `"ScrollToPosition(0)"`  but it doesn't have any effects.
I want my list always in the top when the ads loaded. What should I do?
Many Thanks.